# "JavaScript: The Good Parts" - Why can delete be used as a property name when the book implies it shouldn't

Tags: javascript

Here's an excerpt from Chapter 2 *Names*:

> A *name* **cannot** be one of these reserved words:
>
> ... **`delete`** ...

Then later in that section:

> *Names* are used for ... property names...

If that's true, then why does this work in my browser console:

```
> a = {};
> a.delete = 1;
> a.delete + 2 === 3
true
```

I'm using "Version 36.0.1985.143 m" of Google Chrome for my browser and Windows 8.1 Enterprise for my OS.

Does the author mean property names **should not** be a reserved word or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the book was written, ECMAScript 3 ruled the earth and that was a true statement.

However, modern browsers are running ECMAScript 5, which has lifted that requirement.

If you have IE, put yourself into IE6 or IE7 compatibility mode and it will fail.

BTW, even with ECMAScript 3, you can still write it as

```
a["delete"]
```